# How to choose only specified words in a line of a text file?

Tags: vb.net, split

I want to display word on a listview selected from a line of a text file, for example "The quick brown fox jump over", now i want to choose only the words "quick fox over" then display them on a listview, my code below

```
         Try
            Dim path As String = openFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim SR As New IO.StreamReader(path)
            Do While SR.Peek() <> -1
                Dim LVItem As New ListViewItem
                StrTemp = SR.ReadLine.Split(New String() {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                LVItem.Text = StrTemp(0).ToString
                ListView1.Items.Add(LVItem)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(1).ToString)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(2).ToString)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(3).ToString)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(4).ToString)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(5).ToString)
                LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(6).ToString)
            Loop
            SR.Close()
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        End Try
```

What it does is it reads line by line of a text file, removes the whitespaces and displays the output onto a listview 1 word each column.
[image: <code>![enter image description here][1]</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want columns 2, 3, 5 and 6:

```
LVItem.Text = StrTemp(2).ToString
ListView1.Items.Add(LVItem)
LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(3).ToString)
LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(5).ToString)
LVItem.SubItems.Add(StrTemp(6).ToString)
```

You'll have to adjust your ListView Column Headers to match the new data that was extracted.